# Como iterar sobre uma stream de uma lista que tem uma array e retornar se true?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, stream

Como eu faço pra obter o objeto da enum com um ID que eu passei como parametro checar um elemento do objeto da enum se verdadeiro?

Meu construtor:

```
private WeaponInterface(int[] weaponId, int speed,
            FightType[] fightType) {
        this.setWeaponIds(weaponId);
        this.speed = speed;
        this.fightType = fightType;
    }
```

O que eu to tentando fazer :

```
        public static WeaponInterface forId(Item item){
        return Arrays.asList(WeaponInterface.values()).stream().
        filter(i -> i.getWeaponIds() == item.getId()).collect(n faço idéia);


    }
```

Comment: @Diego sugiro editar a sua pergunta pois não está claro o que você deseja checar com streams e postar os atributos e modelagem de WeaponInterface e Item.

Comment: em ves do `.collect` tente utilizar `.findFirst().orElse(null)` por exemplo

Comment: @brow-joe Eu fiz isso, mas como vc pode ver, a weaponIds é uma array e o item id é um primario, eu teria que ter um jeito de utlilizar isso que você falou fazendo alguma coisa no filtro

Comment: Legal, acho q intendi o que vc quer fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, veja se isto resolve:

criar um método para comparar se o item está presente dentro de seu array

```
public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key) >= 0;
}
```

Agora basta mudar seu método `forId` para

```
public static WeaponInterface forId(Item item) {
    //Cria o predicate que irá ser aplicado dentro do filter
    Predicate<WeaponInterface> predicate = i -> contains(i.getWeaponIds(), item.getId()); 

    //Pega o array e transforma diretamente para stream
    return Arrays.stream(WeaponInterface.values())
                .filter(predicate)
                //Pega o primeiro item
                .findFirst()
                //Em caso de não encontrado retorna null
                .orElse(null);
}
```